# Text to speech in Mono Console application on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I am working on a console application in C# Mono in desktop MacOS.  Is there a way to execute the Mac's text to speech processor?   I would like the console application to say a sentence based on a string.

Thank you as always in advance.